# Disable Auto-Invoice by Paypal in Magento

Tags: magento, paypal

There is a choice of “SALE” or “AUTHORISATION” in the Magento Paypal settings.  We ideally wish to stay with “SALE” as that covers 99.9% of anything we do (we always have goods in stock).  The “Authorisation” option worries me with the 3 day limit, plus it adds an extra “capture” step that could go wrong later.

So…….

“SALE" works fine but in Magento it automatically creates an INVOICE in the system. Other payment systems we use such as Sofort AG make this setting optional and for a very good reason.

Magento is set so that once you have produced an INVOICE and a SHIPMENT it automatically marks any order as COMPLETE.

We create UPS labels, with a tracking number which of course is added to the SHIPMENT details.  So my problem is:

1. As soon as we try to create a UPS label (without even printing) Magento sets the Paypal orders to COMPLETE.  This is because it has seen an INVOICE
   and a SHIPMENT for an order.

We need to disable a Paypal “SALE” from producing an invoice.  We can easily produce and send the invoice once the shipment has been produced
and sent, and then set it finally to Complete.

Is there a setting I have missed to disable this forced invoice?  I can see a company used to make a module for this purpose but it is out of date for Magento 1.9. (I did try it just in case!!)

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/disable-automatic-generation-of-invoice.html

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no setting to fix this: paypal create an object called transaction and this kind of object should be created with the object invoice. It's not a good practice to don't create invoice and I suggest you to stay away to any component that don't create a transaction.
Probably it works well, but in the flow of order creation when you will evalutate to play with order status. Anyway there is not a setting to do this.

Comment: The invoice and the payment are two different kind of object and I can have an order paid but I do not need (or want) an invoice.

Comment: You can have an order "paid" setting the amount to due in an order as 0, but this don't respect the order payment flow of magento. It could be a risk when using triggers or cron checking for the correct status of an order.
Anyway you cannot link a payment object to the order without creating an invoice (using objects of Magento of course). If you'll use native methods it could broke something, be careful.